# Userscript: run code before submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, greasemonkey, userscripts

Currently making a user script. Issue I'm having is that when this one submit button is click, my code is not run. Any help?

```
$('#quick_reply_submit, input[value="Post Reply"]').click(function()
{
    clearCookie();
});
```

In `clearCookie()`, I'm just deleting a cookie. Alert()'ing a message works fine. I've tried return false but that doesn't work, either.

--

The HTML:

`<input type="submit" class="button" name="submit" value="Post Reply" tabindex="3" accesskey="s">`

As I say, there's nothing wrong with the selector. A message is being alert()'ed, but no code after.

--

EDIT: Fixed. See my answer.

Comment: If you put an alert *inside* the clearCookie() function, does it alert as well?

Comment: I don't see an element with id quick_reply_submit in your code sample. Also, should the comma be there after the id in your selector? Are you trying to put the click() handler to two elements or just the button?

Comment: I'm trying to put it on both. The selectors are fine. The alert inside of the clearCookie() functions works, yes :)

Comment: So the clearCookie() function seems to not working? Maybe you should include the source for that function in your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was my fault. Nothing to do with the selectors or the code above.

I was removing a cookie when the button was `clicked`, however I was re-saving the cookie on `blur` which was the problem.